# How to use CDetailView with CArrayDataProvider?

Tags: php, yii

I am trying to fetch data from SQL Server Stored Procedures so I am using the createCommand method in YII Framework.

I have created the gridView but in the CDetailView there's nothing showing using the samethings.

I used:

```
public function getHotel($id = 0){

        /**
         * Building Query for Getting Hotel List Stored Procedure with
         * or Without Parameter defined
         */
        $sql = "EXECUTE procName '".$id."'";

        /**
         * Set Database Connection and instruct Yii Query Builder to Execute SQL
         */
        $connection = Yii::app()->db;
        $command = $connection->createCommand($sql);

        /**
         * Execute the stored procedure.
         */

        $results = $command->queryAll();

        /**
         * Set the DataProvider that will be used in Grid
         */

        $sqlDataProvider = new CArrayDataProvider($results,array(
            'keyField'      => 'hotel_id',
        ));

        /**
         * Return DataProvider
         */

        return $sqlDataProvider;

    }
```

It is providing me the array correctly with the desired id data, but when I am using CDetailView in the view.php so nothing is showing me.

Here's my Controller Code:

```
public function actionView($id)
{

        /**
         * Call the method to generate the CArrayDataProvider by executing the stored procedure.
         */

        $dataProvider = Hotel::model()->getHotel($id);
        $model = new Hotel('getHotel('.$id.')');

        /**
         * Return with the webpage that contains the data grid using the $dataProvider
         * generated earlier
         */

        $this->render('view',array(
            'dataProvider'  => $dataProvider,
            'model'         => $model,
        ));

}
```

Here's view.php Code:

```
<h1>View Hotel #<?php echo $model->hotel_id; ?></h1>

<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CDetailView', array(
    'data'=>$dataProvider,
    'attributes'=>array(
        'hotel_id',
        'name',
        'category_id',
        'currency_id',
        'facility',
        'rel_days',
        'city_id',
        'country_id',
        'telephone',
        'location',
        'email',
        'fax',
        'contact_person',
        'website',
        'address',
        'gl_id',
        'policy',
        'status',
        'date_added',
        'date_modified',
        'user_id',
    ),
)); ?>
```

Output I am getting on the broswer is like:

> Hotel ID : Not Set
>
> Name : Not Set
>
> .
>
> .
>
> .
>
> .
>
> .
>
> .
>
> .
>
> .
>
> User ID : Not Set

Please help me out to sort this out.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem.

I replaced the function getHotel($id = 0) with the following:

```
public function getHotel($id = 0){

        /**
         * Building Query for Getting Hotel List Stored Procedure with
         * or Without Parameter defined
         */
        $sql = "EXECUTE viewHotel '".$id."'";

        /**
         * Set Database Connection and instruct Yii Query Builder to Execute SQL
         */
        $connection = Yii::app()->db;
        $command = $connection->createCommand($sql);

        /**
         * Execute the stored procedure.
         */

        $results = $command->queryAll();
        foreach($results as $result){

            foreach($result as $key=>$val){
                $hotels[$key] = $val;
            }

        }

        return $hotels;

    }
```

Actually, $results = $command->queryAll(); returns a multi-dimensional array so I converted into simple array with index and its value then return it to the controller to render it in CDetailView.

Thanks for your support!

Answer (score 0):

maybe I'm wrong but CdetailView work with one element of model and you get an Array

```
$model = KPI::model()->findByPk($id); - It is one element
$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbDetailView', array(
        'data'=>$model,
        'itemCssClass'=>array('detailViewTr'),
        'attributes'=>array(                                    
            'description',
            'field',
            'dt_from',
            'dt_to',
            array('name'=>'period','value'=>$period[$model->period]),
            array('value'=>$model->user->fio,'name'=>'KPI создал'),             
            array('value'=>$model->direction->caption,'name'=>'Отдел заказчик')
        ),
    ));
```

Answer (score 0):

For a `CDetailView` you should **not** use the `CArrayDataProvider`. You should use a model, the `CActiveRecord` is usually for SQL-databases.

Given that `$model = new Hotel('getHotel('.$id.')');` return a `CModel` object, this should work for you.

Change your view.php to:

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CDetailView', array(
    'data'=>$model,
    'attributes'=>array(
        'hotel_id',
        'name',
        ...
        'user_id',
    ),
)); ?>
```

Have a look at this tutorial http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.ar

Comment: Actually I am using stored procedure from SQL Server to get data, and CActiveRecord is not applicable with Stored Procedures, thats why I am using the function "createCommand" and then CArrayDataProvider.